# Retrieve item from std::map in function marked const

Tags: c++, constants, stdmap

Consider the following C++ code:

```
// A.h
class A {
private:
    std::map<int, int> m;
    int getValue(int key) const;
};

// A.cpp
int A::getValue(int key) const {
    // build error: 
    // No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::map<int, int>'
    return m[key];
}
```

How can I grab the value from `m` such that it works in the context of a `const` function?

Comment: Important to note that `operator[]` is not `const` because if the key is not found, it is added to the map with a default value.  `operator[]` cannot be `const` because it can change the `map`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option is to use the `at()` method, which is `const` and will throw an exception if the key is not found.

```
int A::getValue(int key) const 
{
  return m.at(key);
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to decide what to return in the case where the key is not found. If there is a value you can return in these cases, then you can use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

```
int A::getValue(int key) const 
{
  auto it = m.find(key);
  return (it != m.end()) ? it->second : TheNotFoundValue;
}
```

Comment: In addition, consider defining the variable as mutable if you would like to allow a default object to be inserted when the key is not found.